# Splitting an array remains as array of one item rather than a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a javascript array of objects, where there is a property with another array as value, as seen here:

```
var data = [
{
id: 1,
parent: [1,2,3,4]
}, 
{
id: 2,
parent: [5,6,7,8]
}
]
```

I am trying to split it, so every object with more than one parent, gets a duplicated copy of itself, each copy with a different parent. I have done this so far:

```
var updateddata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

for (var i = 0; i < updateddata[i].parent.length; i++) {
    while (updateddata[i].parent.length > 1) {
        updateddata.push({
        id: updateddata[i].id,
        parent: updateddata[i].parent[0]
    })
updateddata[i].parent.shift()
}
}
```

And it works perfect, except for the fact that when doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(updateddata))` I can see that the first two entries have as a parent an array with one single entry, unlike the others, which are already outside the array:

This is the `console.log` for `updateddata`:

```
[
{"id":1,"parent":[4]},
{"id":2,"parent":[8]},
{"id":1,"parent":1},
{"id":1,"parent":2},
{"id":1,"parent":3},
{"id":2,"parent":5},
{"id":2,"parent":6},
{"id":2,"parent":7}
]
```

I have also tried to use `.toString()` in the values, but it didn't make any difference.

How could I solve it?

Comment: You should do your while loop until 0, since you are not checking if length equals 0. You are not reading the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `reduce()` and `forEach()` loop

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  parent: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}, {
  id: 2,
  parent: [5, 6, 7, 8]
}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, ar) {
  ar.parent.forEach(function(e) {
    r.push({id: ar.id, parent: e});
  });
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. I decided to accept this answer, as the method you use is interesting and I didn't know it, so I will keep reading about that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you needed?

```
var data = [
{
id: 1,
parent: [1,2,3,4]
}, 
{
id: 2,
parent: [5,6,7,8]
}
]

var updatedData = [];

data.forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.parent.length > 1) {
    obj.parent.forEach((value) => {
      updatedData.push({
        id: obj.id,
        parent: [value]
      });
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It should be `parent: value` instead, as I wanted the value outside the array, but this is pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use for loop to traverse the array:

```
var data = [
{
id: 1,
parent: [1,2,3,4]
}, 
{
id: 2,
parent: [5,6,7,8]
}
];
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    for(var j=0;j<obj.parent.length; j++) {
        result.push({id: obj["id"], parent: obj.parent[j]});
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

THe result will print the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I will still write the answer to use you code correctly since you had something working :

```
for (var i = 0; i < updateddata[i].parent.length; i++) {
    while (updateddata[i].parent.length > 0) { // Here you should read the last one
        updateddata.push({
        id: updateddata[i].id,
        parent: updateddata[i].parent[0]
        })
        updateddata[i].parent.shift()
    }
}
```

Of course this will keep the empty array at the beginning. Two solutions, remove after treatment or when length = 1 change parent array into the value

Answer (score 1):

I think `reduce`, `concat`, and `map` yield a more declarative solution.

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, parent: [1,2,3,4] }, 
  { id: 2, parent: [5,6,7,8] }
]

let result = data.reduce((acc, {id, parent}) =>
  [...acc, ...parent.map(x => ({id, parent:x}))], [])
   
console.log(result)
```

If you define the **shape** of the output data ahead of time, it makes things a bit better yet

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, parent: [1,2,3,4] }, 
  { id: 2, parent: [5,6,7,8] }
]

let shape = id => parent => ({id, parent})

let result = data.reduce((acc, {id, parent}) =>
  [...acc, ...parent.map(shape(id))], [])
   
console.log(result)
```